Class JakartaServletFileUpload, The import org.apache.commons.fileupload cannot be resolved
I reference the link https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html
and replace ServletFileUpload with JakartaServletFileUpload.
I already add fileupload2 dependency in my pom.xml as follow:
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-fileupload2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-M2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<!--  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

but in java file, the following import are fail
import org.apache.commons.fileupload2.jakarta;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload2.core;

it returns

The import org.apache.commons.fileupload2 cannot be resolved

and so the following has errors also
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    factory.setSizeThreshold(MEMORY_THRESHOLD); 
    factory.setRepository(new File(appProp.getTempDir()));
    JakartaServletFileUpload  upload = new JakartaServletFileUpload(factory);

So

why the imports is failed?
I see the commons-fileupload2 pom.xml https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-fileupload2/2.0.0-M2
already has dependencies for commons-io, commons-lang3..., so is I need to remove the previously added commons-io, commons-lang3...dependency in my previous pom.xml?

---------------- Edit --------------------
I check maven dependencies,
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

does not download any jar about Commons FileUpload. Then what is it used for? At first I think it is used to download the jar mentioned in the pom.xml
